# Why does my cursor disappear when i change from my obscureText activated textfield to a normal textfield? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a login screen and I am having problems with input and focus. If I start filling out the email part and then the password part, I get no problems. But when I switch the focus to the **email ** from the **password ** text field the cursor disappears and anything I type doesn't appear on the screen.

````
  InputTextField({super.key, required this.label, this.obscureText = false});
  final String label;
  bool obscureText;

  @override
  State<InputTextField> createState() => _InputTextFieldState();
}

class _InputTextFieldState extends State<InputTextField> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      style: kTextStyle,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      cursorColor: kDarkBlue,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Please enter your ${widget.label}.',
        hintStyle: kTextStyle,
        filled: true,
        fillColor: const Color(0xFF9DB2BF),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
        ),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      ),
      keyboardType: widget.label == 'email' ? TextInputType.emailAddress : null,
      obscureText: widget.obscureText,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (widget.label == 'password') {
          setState(() {
            widget.obscureText = true;
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }
}```

I've tried focus nodes but I couldn't quite get it to do what I want to do. Taking out the obscure text property makes all the problems disappear but I want to use it for the password text field.
````